# jQuery use this in done function doesn't work

Tags: jquery, this

I have a problem with ajax function. Code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#stage1 > div > div").live("click", function() {
    var cat=jQuery(this).parent().index() + 1;
    alert(cat);
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo get_permalink(177); ?>",
            data: {
                    curPage: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
                    id: cat }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        jQuery(this).html(msg);
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is with `this` in done function. I have firebug in firefox, that's why I know data is returned, it should be displayed, but it doesn't. I assume `jQuery(this)` is a problem. Is anyone know how to use `this` in done function?

Comment: live() is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` inside `.done()` refers to a different object than the `this` which you want. Also, use `.on()` instead of `.live()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#stage1 > div > div").live("click", function() {
    var cat=jQuery(this).parent().index() + 1;
    alert(cat);
    var self = this;
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo get_permalink(177); ?>",
            data: {
                    curPage: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
                    id: cat }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        jQuery(self).html(msg);
    });
});
</script>
```

You can use `console.log(this)` tocheck how it differs. To read more about `this` keyword check out [this on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: Thanks for posting the exact same answer as me just a second quicker

Comment: SO is not a race. You can post a better answer explaining him rather than just posting code like I did. And I would be more than happy to upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery(this)` doesn''t work into your function done because this is refered to the ajax function.
I advise you to save your object prevoius and after call him like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#stage1 > div > div").live("click", function() {
    var obj = this;
    var cat=jQuery(this).parent().index() + 1;
    alert(cat);

    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo get_permalink(177); ?>",
            data: {
                    curPage: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
                    id: cat }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        jQuery(obj).html(msg);
    });
});
</script>
```

Other solution is to save the id and after with jQuery select the element byId, but this cannot work into your function directly

Answer (score 0):

That is because `this` is not bound to the original element in your `done()` callback. Instead, it is bound to a mixin between `$.ajaxSettings` and the AJAX options you passed.

To preserve the original context, you can specify `this` in the `context` option passed to [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    context: this,
    type: "GET",
    url: "<?php echo get_permalink(177); ?>",
    data: {
        curPage: <?php echo $post->ID; ?>,
        id: cat
    }
}).done(function(msg) {
    jQuery(this).html(msg);  // Will work as expected.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use closure:  {just an another way}

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#stage1 > div > div").live("click", function () {
    var cat = jQuery(this).parent().index() + 1;
    alert(cat);
    (function (self) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?php echo get_permalink(177); ?>",
            data: {
                curPage: <? php echo $post - > ID; ?> ,
                id: cat
            }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            jQuery(self).html(msg);
        });
    }(this));
});
</script>
```